# Eloquent does not recognize fillable fields when adding constructor to model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have model `Category` as below:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var $fillable
     */
    protected $fillable = array('title', 'slug' , 'descriptoin', 'cover', 'logo', 'parent_id');

    /**
     * @var $category_logo_pathp
     */
    protected $category_logo_path ;

    /**
     * @var $category_cover_path
     */
    protected $category_cover_path ;

    /**
     * constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->category_cover_path = public_path() . '/upload/image/category/cover/';
        $this->category_logo_path = public_path() . '/upload/image/category/logo/';
    }

    /**
     * relation with itself
     */
    public function parent()
    {
        return self::where('id', $this->parent_id)->first();
    }

    public function coverPath()
    {
        return $this->category_cover_path;
    }

    public function logoPath()
    {
        return $this->category_logo_path;
    }
}
```

When inserting a category instance with correct data into database , Eloquent does not recognize fillable fields of the model and then throws `Illuminate\Database\QueryException` but when i remove the constructor from category model , it works fine and fillable fields are recognized using Eloquent. what is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sure, you should run parent constructor and probably it's quite reasonable to use default Model signature, so your constructor should look like this:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
   parent::__construct($attributes);
   $this->category_cover_path = public_path() . '/upload/image/category/cover/';
   $this->category_logo_path = public_path() . '/upload/image/category/logo/';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works fine now....but how attributes are injected into model constructor?

Comment: @ako You can run new `$category = new Category(['title' => 'Sample title']); $category->save(); ` for example